# Create Windows 7 installation medium?

Tags: windows-7, installation

Using tools such as [slipstreamer.exe](http://www.heise.de/download/ct-slipstreamer.html?zanpid=1850838875069965312), it is possible to create a pristine install
disk from an existing Windows XP installation.

*Is something similar possible with Windows 7?*

Background: I want to make a fresh install of Windows 7 on a new laptop, i.e.
without the bloatware preinstalled by the vendor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to build my own install discs like you want to. I've also tried with Windows 7, however I'm not exactly an expert in this field. But anyway, here's what I've learned, perhaps it'll save you some time.

**First:** As far as I know it's not possible to create a Windows 7 install disc from an installation.

**Second:** While tools exist to create a custom install DVD, these tools never seemed to reach a complete state like they did for Windows XP, and even Vista. I never found a tool that worked for Win7 SP1. This means that the best "slipstreamed" DVD it's possible to create/find is the original Win7 SP1 DVD.

**Third:** At least things have gotten easier since Windows XP. Back then it was very important to find the exact right version of the disc to install to a specific product key.(OEM/Retail, Proffessional/home, Vendor specific. And any combination of these..)

I've found that for Windows 7 the retail disc works for all pc's that I've had to reinstall. As long as the product key is entered, and validated, the actual disc used seems not to be important.

**Solution:**
This means that you should simply get hold of a Windows 7 SP1 disc. (It might not even be important that it's the right kind. E.g. home/ultimate/etc. However I've never tried anything else than home edition.)

As far as I know it's legal enough to borrow a DVD from a friend, as long as you use your own product key.

If you don't have any friends with the DVD, it should be possible, and legal, to download the ISOs from Digital River. More about that here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/comment-page-1/

Comment: Very informative, thanks a lot! I also found some of the same information when searching the web. If there was a reliable way to create a pristine installation disk from an existing installation, I guess it would be easy to find, but there was nothing.